# Does Kalai's $3^d$ conjecture hold for simplicial spheres?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, simplicial-complexes

[Kalai's $3^d$ conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalai%27s_3%5Ed_conjecture) asserts that every centrally symmetric $d$-polytope has at least $3^d$ non-empty faces. This is open in general, but has been proven for [*simplicial polytopes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytope).

> **Question:** Does the conjecture still hold for centrally symmetric *simplicial spheres*? Or are counterexamples known?

Here, a [simplicial sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_sphere) is a simplicial complex that is homeomorphic to a sphere, but is not neccessarily the boundary complex of a simplicial polytope. I am not sure how to best formalize "centrally symmetric" in this context, but one idea would be to require a fixed-point free involution on the sphere.

Comment: Your definition of centrally symmetric simplicial complex is the standard one: see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09310

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference for Kalai's conjecture for simplicial polytopes is Richard Stanley's paper [On the number of faces of centrally-symmetric simplicial polytopes](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01788529)
 which includes the theorem:

> Let $A$ be a $(d - 1)$-dimensional Cohen-Macaulay simplicial complex,
> and suppose that a group $G$ of order $2$ acts freely on $A$. Then
> $$ h_i(A) \geq \binom{d}{i}$$ for $i$ from $0$ to $d$.

I think this theorem gives what you ask for.

Simplicial spheres (and all simplicial manifolds) are Cohen-Macauley by Reisner's theorem. The group $G$ acting freely is the same as being centrally-symmetric. And the relation between the $h_i$ and the number $f_i$ of faces of dimension $i$ gives

$$f_{i-1}  = \sum_{k=0}^{i} \binom{d-k}{i-k} h_k \geq  \sum_{k=0}^{i} \binom{d-k}{i-k} \binom{d}{k} = 2^i \binom{d}{i}$$

so $$ \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} f_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^d 2^i \binom{d}{i}  = 3^d-1$$ which is Kalai's conjecture (after subtracting off the $d$-dimensional face which is counted as part of the simplicial polytope for Kalai's purposes but not counted as part of the simplicial sphere).